# Return select from for loop postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
do $do$
declare
    temprow record;
BEGIN 
    FOR temprow IN
    select *
    from log l 
    inner join sales s on s.id = l.sale_id
    where s.column_a = '88'
    and s.date_added > '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    and event_subject in ('event_A', 'event_B')
    loop 
        select * 
        from log 
        where log.sale_id= temprow.sale_id
        and log.supplier_id <> temprow.supplier_id
        and log.event_subject in ('event_C', 'event_D')
        and log.ip = temprow.ip;                                                                                                                        
    end loop;
end
$do$;
```

How do I get results of select query inside a loop ?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: There are records in log table with event_subject = event_A or event_B with specific "ip" and "supplier_id" values. There are also records with event_subject=event_C or event_D, which has different 'supplier_id" value but share the same "ip" value. I want to find those records.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you think think about using loops in SQL you are doing something wrong. As far as I can tell, your problem can be solved with a single query:

```
select log.*
from log 
where log.event_subject in ('event_C', 'event_D')
  and exists (select *
              from log l 
                join sales s on s.id = l.sale_id
              where s.column_a = '88'
                and s.date_added > '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
                and l.event_subject in ('event_A', 'event_B')
                and log.ip = l.ip
                and log.sale_id = l.sale_id
                and log.supplier_id <> l.supplier_id)
```